# Snowflake Using Regular Expressions to Remove Values from a Column

Tags: string, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use regular expressions to remove some weirdly formatted dates from a column.

I found [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html), but it seems that only works on literal strings, not an entire column.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit #1:**

This is what my data looks like

```
Col_A
20-APR-30
20-FEB-25
2021-12-01
2021-12-10 00:00:00
20211210
```

Desired output is that all values are in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: Share weirdly formatted dates, share desired results please. I don't see why this wouldn't work on an entire column.

Comment: Edited to include data and desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different formats need different formattings:

```sql
select try_to_date($1,'YY-MON-DD') a
    , try_to_date($1,'YYYY-MM-DD') b
    , try_to_date($1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') c
    , try_to_date($1,'YYYYMMDD') d
from values('20-APR-30'),('20-FEB-25'),('2021-12-01'),('2021-12-10 00:00:00'),('20211210')
```

[image]

Then coalesce:

```sql
select coalesce(
        try_to_date($1,'YY-MON-DD') 
        , try_to_date($1,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        , try_to_date($1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') 
        , try_to_date($1,'YYYYMMDD') 
    ) fixed
    , $1 original
from values('20-APR-30'),('20-FEB-25'),('2021-12-01'),('2021-12-10 00:00:00'),('20211210')
;
```

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem, but before I mark it as solved, can you explain, the $1?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html

I don't see that there?

Comment: The $1 is the name of the column that doesn't have a name, because I just created that table with the SELECT FROM VALUES. Use your column names as appropriate